# Why are images in my IntelliJ IDEA project accessible to some Java classes but aren't to others in JavaFX?

Tags: java, image, javafx, loading

I'm working on a simple 2D game in JavaFX, and I loaded some of my assets (just a bunch of folders and images) into my project into their own directory, and went to make another Java class for all the stuff the player needs (movement, keypress, loading player assets), and none of the images are loading. Does anyone know why? I have the code I know is causing the problem below.

```
class Player
{
    public Player() throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    Image leftSide = new Image(new FileInputStream("resources/player/leftNO.png");
    ImageView leftSideView = new ImageView(leftSide);
}
```

My directory is listed below:

- .idea
- out
- resources

  - player

    - leftNO.png
    - rightNO.png
- src

  - sample

    - Main.java
    - Player.java

Anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance, even if you don't have an answer.

EDIT: Also, I forgot to mention that when I try to open the image in the Main.java class, it loads fine.

Comment: @user I've tried that, it didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: ...do you know what `System.exit` does? Do you know what the purpose of a constructor is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say not loading, do you mean that it throws an exception or is blank?
Depending on which, this could work:

Mark your resources directory as a source folder and try

```
class Player
{
    public Player() throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    Image leftSide = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/leftNO.png");
    ImageView leftSideView = new ImageView(leftSide);
}
```

This will also allow you app to work from within a jar

Comment: When I said not loading, I meant its blank because the constructor (I don't know exactly how to phrase this) went like this: 
`public Player() throws FileNotFoundException
{
        System.exit(-1);
}`

Comment: No problem, but why are you calling System.exit()? That could cause a lot of problems in the future and I can't imagine a need for it there.                                                   P.S. Could you mark the answer as correct to help anyone else with the question. Thx

Comment: I'm calling it because I want it to end the program, should I throw a new error or print the stack trace? I'm still pretty new to Java and JavaFX and don't know much.

Comment: @AndrewBota but why would you want to end the program every time you instantiate the object? A constructor is called each time the obbject is created. As a rule, if it's an exception that's only thrown when you or your code make a mistake, throw it, if its something that is only thrown when the user makes a mistake catch it and handle it properly (i.e. not just a printstacktrace).

Comment: continued from above: For example, your user is prompted to select a file, they don't and a FileNotFound exception is thrown, catch it and dispolay a prompt telling the user to select a proper file (of course ideally you would just chjeck the files validfity and avoid the exception alltogetrher).